# How to write code snippet in apiary.io?

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

I am using apiary.io and added all restful endpoints. It looks great, there are code snippets in many languages how to make GET request and get the results.

Now, I want to add a code snippet to the documentation, which is not related to any endpoints (example for the authentication process). I want this code to be shown on the right, without clicking on any link. Can I somehow achieve this? I would like to have the code highlighted and indented as in my IDE. I am using Python, if that is relevant.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "*code to be shown on the right*" you mean in the machine column (the rightest one) with another code examples. If I am correct, I have to disappoint you - unfortunately it's not possible as machine column is generated from HTTP resources only.

You can put your code example into documentation using standard [Markdown syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), e.g.:

> ```python
>
> ```
> s = "Python syntax highlighting"
> print s
> ```
>
> ```

Comment: I realized it is not possible to be shown on the right. Thanks for the suggestion! BTW, it would be nice to make the code snippets look a little bit more colorful, like in IDE or notepad/gedit. Like here: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code